# Browning on Silver Spurflower leaves? Is this a fungus or lack of water?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, diseases, container-gardening

I have noticed over the last week my Silver Spurflower leaves have started to go brown and start curling. They are in large containers and other plants in the containers have also been getting similar browning on the edges of their leaves.

I'm in the UK, Zone 7, they are east facing and get a lot of rain normally but we have had a dry patch recently when I was away.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: browning silver spurflower]

Comment: Good question and illustration; if could include an overall illustration, overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, size of container, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

This is a general sign of hot and dry summer days, many potted plants show this behavior. Here in the Netherlands we just recently had a very hot and dry period for more than a week (heat wave), and I have some potted plants too with brown edges.

This is caused by the combination of drought and heat. Even if you water the plants daily, it is still not enough for the plant to take it up. Some plants are more prone to this than others. You can try to prevent it by putting it in the shade next time when dry and hot weather is coming.

For now, your plants will survive, if you want you can remove the affected leaves when enough new healthy leaves are formed.